# Exogenous variable having opposite effect on forecasted values in SARIMAX model

Tags: arima, modeling, exogeneity

I'm modeling how many plays are made on arcade machines at a store, using the number of active machines as an exogenous variable. I'm forecasting the number of plays into the future while keeping the number of devices the same, decreasing device count, and increasing device count. What's odd is I'm seeing the opposite effect of what I'd expect: when device count increases, there is decrease in forecasted plays, while when there is a decrease in device count, there is an increase in forecasted plays. Why would these changes in the exogenous variable have counter-intuitive effects on the model?

Comment: What other variables are there in the model?

Comment: One endogenous variable - the total number of games played. It is a daily time series with weekly seasonality. Two exogenous variables: one dummy variable for holidays, and then one for the number of active devices (how many devices were played on that day).

Comment: Is it possible that new machines are brought in when customers get bored of playing the existing ones, and then people switch to the new games once words gets out and old ones get phased out? In that case, the number of machines would have a negative effect on games. In other words, the number of machines is a choice variable for the arcade, so it could be endogenous (i.e., related to the error term). You often see a similar pattern with advertising expenditures. One solution would be to have vintages of machines in the model rather than a total count.